# Issue with creating Custom Tag Libraries in CQ5.5

Tags: osgi, jsp-tags, aem, osgi-bundle

I am creating a custom tag library and want to use it in one of my components. I have created a bundle which includes tag hello class which is extending TagSupport class and i created tags.tld file under my resource folder

In my pom.xml, I have used resource tag to include my .tld file in the generated jar file.

Here is my java class and tld file

TAG CLASS:-

```
package com.cb;
import javax.servlet.jsp.*;
import javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.*;
/**
* Simple tag example to show how content is added to the
* output stream when a tag is encountered in a JSP page.
*/
public class Hello extends TagSupport {
private String name=null;
  /**
   * Getter/Setter for the attribute name
     as defined in the tld file
   * for this tag*/
public void setName(String value){
    name = value;
}
public String getName(){
      return(name);
}
/**
* doStartTag is called by the JSP container
  when the tag is encountered */
public int doStartTag() {
  try {
    JspWriter out = pageContext.getOut();
    out.println("<table border=\"1\">");
     if (name != null)
      out.println("<tr><td> Welcome <b>" + name +
        "</b> </td></tr>");
    else
      out.println("<tr><td> Hello World </td></tr></table>");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new Error("All is not well in the world.");
  }
  // Must return SKIP_BODY because we are not
       //supporting a body for this
  // tag.
  return SKIP_BODY;
}
/**
* doEndTag is called by the
  JSP container when the tag is closed */
public int doEndTag(){
   return EVAL_PAGE;
}
}
```

I also successfully installed the bundle in my felix console without having any error. Then i written custom tag in my jsp as below

JSP:-

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
<%@ page import="com.testcb.TestCustomTag"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="mytest" uri="http://cs.test.com/bundles/cq/1.8"%>
<mytest:hello name="sachin"></mytest:hello>
```

I am getting the like "org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: /apps/test/components/content/test/test.jsp(4,0) Unable to load tag handler class "com.cb.Hello" for tag "mytest:hello".

The same code is working fine in my apache tomcat server without having any issue. I am getting the error when i incorporate it in CQ.

What am i doing here? Is there any config i need to do in OSGI console to make it available?

**UPDATE:**

There was some problem with package name. Now Sling can read my tag handler class after i renamed the package name.

The error "Unable to load tag handler class" also has gone.

Now i am getting error as "***org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.testcb.TestCustomTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag***"

I have the following dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And Here is my tld

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd" version="2.0"> 
    <description>My tag library123</description>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>TagLib-Test</short-name>
    <uri>http://cs.test.com/bundles/cq/1.0</uri>
    <jspversion>2.1</jspversion>
    <tag>
      <name>testcustomtag</name>
      <tagclass>com.testcb.TestCustomTag</tagclass>
      <bodycontent>empty</bodycontent>
      <info>This is a simple hello tag</info>
    <attribute>
      <name>name</name>
      <required>true</required>
      <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    </tag>
</taglib>
```

Is there any problem with jsp version?

Please guide me to resolve.

Thanks

Comment: in your tld you have `<uri>http://cs.test.com/bundles/cq/1.8</uri>` and in your jsp you have in the taglib `uri="http://cs.test.com/bundles/cq/1.9"` the uri needs to be the same in both places.

Comment: Hi, I have been using same URI in both places. Sorry i forgot to change the version while posting  here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is working as expected after i removed  tag in pom.xml. This was the cause issues. :)

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The tags.tld file needs to be under the META-INF folder. If you don't have it already you can create one under your resources source folder.

Comment: It looks like the TLD is being read - otherwise you wouldn't get the class name in the error message.Here is my maven folder strusture

bundle -> src -> main -> java -> com-> cb -> Hello.java
bundle -> src -> main -> resources -> tags.tld

and here is my jar file structure

cb-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT -> META-INF -> tags.tld
cb-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT -> OSGI-INF -> .....
cb-bundle-1.0-SNAPSHOT -> com.cb -> Hello.class

Comment: I've replicate your structure in my CQ5.5 and I'm not having any issues. Is it possible that you have an additional bundle somewhere that is exposing the same structure of com.cb?

Comment: Thanks, there was some problem with package name now i renamed it. The error "Unable to load tag handler class" also has gone. Now i am getting error as "org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: com.gecb.TestCustomTag cannot be cast to javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.Tag" I have updated my post. Please check is there any jsp version issue.